# Encode AWS KMS asymmetric key sign/verify signature to base64 and verify

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, base64, amazon-kms

I am using an AWS KMS asymmetric ECC (ES256) key to sign and verify tokens using API calls in Python3. The response returns

```
{
    "KeyId": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:000000000000:key/1234",
    "Signature": "b'0D\\x02 \\x18\\xd9\\x13\\x96\\x9d\\xb00p\\xc9H\\'-\\xc6@{\\xd1V\\xf5\\xeb\\x83\"1\\x0e:\\x98\\xb4\\xea6P\\x0f\\xdf\\x82\\x02 \\x1fPt\\xc0\\x81pB\\xaa\\xe7_\\xf2~\\x91BlU\\x05\\xba1\\xe0\\xfe\\xf6\\xe4\\xebL\\nl\\xfc\\xf8\\xce\\xc6_'",
    "SigningAlgorithm": "ECDSA_SHA_256"
```

}

If I use AWS CLI the response "Signature" is base64 encoded:

```
{
    "KeyId": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:000000000000:key/1234",
    "Signature": "MEQCIBqjAiAnMKkugooWU6/AqCyfhQUocoiVeIIf8lL2p7YbAiBEJOl2cp9HzQNufiMBezIjZuSGW6ID13l7JSzTgLlv+g==",
    "SigningAlgorithm": "ECDSA_SHA_256"
}
```

Whenever I attempt to base64 encode `base64.urlsafe_b64encode(string)` the "Signature" using the API response in Python3, I cannot verify the signature. Here's an example of the error I receive:

> An error occurred (InvalidKeyUsageException) when calling the Verify
> operation: asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:1
> tag:2 length:39 isCompound:true}) {optional:false explicit:false
> application:false private:false defaultValue: tag:
> stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} ecdsaSignature @2

How can I base64 encode the "Signature" bytes string returned from the API and still be able to verify?

UPDATE:

If I update to `base64.b4encode` instead of `base64.urlsafe_encode` I get the same result:

```
def _sign_token(self, key_id, message):
    signature = kms_client.sign(
        KeyId=key_id,
        Message=message,
        MessageType="RAW",
        SigningAlgorithm="ECDSA_SHA_256",
    )
    logger.log(msg=signature, level=cl.log_level)
    return base64.b64encode(signature["Signature"]).decode()
```

log message returns:

> {"asctime": "2021-04-03 19:40:27,593", "levelname": "INFO", "name":
> "util.sign", "lineno": 214, "message": null, "env": "local", "KeyId":
> "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:000000000000:key/309d8dc5-409e-4f57-96a8-c71223c84dc2",
> "Signature":
> "b'0E\x02!\x00\xcc\x82\xf4$@?\x9e\n\xd7$\x94\x9f.\x1d5\x19{W\x1e\xcff\x8b&\xf0\xef\x88\xcf^"\xf6\xa4\x1b\x02
> \x0c\x18\xab?\x93\xd5\x88Cx\xf6\x0c\x1b\xcf\xd9\xd9\xd2\xd4"\xcf\x94\xede_>\x8c\x01~J\xea\x0ezB'",
> "SigningAlgorithm": "ECDSA_SHA_256", "ResponseMetadata":
> {"HTTPStatusCode": 200, "HTTPHeaders": {"content-type":
> "application/x-amz-json-1.1", "content-length": "233", "connection":
> "close", "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
> "access-control-allow-methods":
> "HEAD,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,PATCH",
> "access-control-allow-headers":
> "authorization,content-type,content-length,content-md5,cache-control,x-amz-content-sha256,x-amz-date,x-amz-security-token,x-amz-user-agent,x-amz-target,x-amz-acl,x-amz-version-id,x-localstack-target,x-amz-tagging", "access-control-expose-headers": "x-amz-version-id", "date": "Sat, 03
> Apr 2021 19:40:27 GMT", "server": "hypercorn-h11"}, "RetryAttempts":
> 0}}

Verify error:

> "stacktrace": "An error occurred (InvalidKeyUsageException) when
> calling the Verify operation: asn1: structure error: tags don't match
> (16 vs {class:1 tag:13 length:69 isCompound:false}) {optional:false
> explicit:false application:false private:false defaultValue:
> tag: stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false}
> ecdsaSignature @2"

```
def _verify_signature(self, key_id, message, signature):
    response = kms_client.verify(
        KeyId=key_id,
        Message=message,
        MessageType="RAW",
        Signature=signature,
        SigningAlgorithm="ECDSA_SHA_256",
    )
    logger.log(msg=response, level=cl.log_level)
    return response
```

client.verify requires signature to be bytes https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.11.4/reference/services/kms.html#KMS.Client.verify

If I leave off the `.encode()` I get the same:

> "stacktrace": "An error occurred (InvalidKeyUsageException) when
> calling the Verify operation: asn1: structure error: tags don't match
> (16 vs {class:1 tag:13 length:69 isCompound:false}) {optional:false
> explicit:false application:false private:false defaultValue:
> tag: stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false}
> ecdsaSignature @2"

```
def _sign_token(self, key_id, message):
    signature = kms_client.sign(
        KeyId=key_id,
        Message=message,
        MessageType="RAW",
        SigningAlgorithm="ECDSA_SHA_256",
    )
    logger.log(msg=signature, level=cl.log_level)
    return base64.b64encode(signature["Signature"])
```

NOTE:

**If I pass the client.sign response "Signature" to client.verify without base64 encoding, verification passes.**

Answer (score 1):

The string encoded by AWS cli is *not* urlsafe-base64 encoded! It is encoded using the standard base64, i.e. `base64.b64encode`.

Standard base64 encoding uses three metacharacters `/`, `+` and `=`. `/` and `+` are not safe to use in either paths or query strings, and URL-safe encoding replaces these two with `_` and `-` respectively. Since `/` and `+` are present in the AWS CLI encoded string, it can be deduced that it uses standard base64 encoding and not the URL-safe one.

The return value of `base64.b64encode` is **`bytes`** object. Usually Base-64 encoding is used to encode binary into text. To get the value as text instead you need to `decode` it (as UTF-8 into unicode string, for example):

```
base64_encoded_as_str = base64.b64encode(binary_value).decode()
```

Comment: That all is true, but it appears I am encoding the " b' " and ending single quote when I base64 encode either url safe or not.

Comment: @swhit ok please read the last paragraph :P

Answer (score 0):

The AWS support process worked. It turned out I was doing a `decode()` operation on the base64 encoded signature when attempting to verify instead of `base64.b64decode()`